# How does Apple make their Swift programming books?

Tags: swift, markdown, epub, ibooks

I'm trying to create a book using a template (or just formatting in general) similar to the ones used with the [Apple Swift Programming Language iBook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11).

I'm struggling with figuring out exactly what software Apple uses to create the book with such simple and clean formatting along with what they use to create the headers, coding samples, comments, etc (is it a special version of Markdown?).

My Google searches with "what apple uses to create books", "what apple uses to create api documentation", "apple software for dev books", etc. didn't really lead to much. The searches themselves might not have been effective either, so there's that possibility.

Regardless, I got answers involving RegexKit, HeaderDocs, and Gentle Bytes, and it didn't seem too relevant to what I was trying to do.

So then I did some digging into the main frameworks that build up the iBook and I found [these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwxRo.png) (there are more but the image only shows some).

Mainly xhtml files.

**So really all I'm asking** is what software does Apple use to combine all these files or did they use a different application that automatically combined them as they inserted them while creating the iBook? Do they even use iBooks Author or rather an internal application that's not available for download outside of Apple? OR maybe it's something that's not related to anything I said and I'm way off track.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an iBook I would assume that they used [iBooks Author](https://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/)

After you created your iBook with iBooks Author, you can convert it to HTML, it will create many files then.